# Where does the use of the term echelon in maths stem from?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

We often employ the term *row echelon form* to describe matrices with a certain pattern, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). My question is, when was the term *echelon* first used to describe a matrix? In particular, was the term used first in maths or in the military?

Some etimology can be found [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/echelon), but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: from French *échelon* (“rung; echelon”), from *échelle* (“ladder”). Maybe because the matrix has a [staircase pattern](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_%C3%A9chelonn%C3%A9e)...